# Video Preview Layer Running While in Split-View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, avcapturesession

I currently have an app that displays the front facing camera atop a video preview layer. By default in iOS 9, the preview layer is interrupted/paused and will not resume until split-view is dismissed. Based on the nature of the app, maintaining the running camera preview layer while multitasking is essential.

Is there any way to force the capture session to continue previewing while in split view?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Seems as if Apple does not allow any sort of camera use while the device has more than one application open. You can, however, invoke UIImagePickerController in order to take a photo while in split-view. Of course this solution only allows you to snap a single photo, and nothing more. Hope this helps someone!